# QML elements undefined from js

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I have a problems changing elements properties from js file. In my program I have main element with that structure:

```
import "main.js" as Main
ApplicationWindow
{
    id: applicationWindow

    VK {
        id: vk
        onReplyReady: {
            if (typeof document === "string") {
                var obj = JSON.parse(document)
                console.log(typeof obj.response,typeof obj.count)
                Main.processReply(obj.response)

            } else {
                Debug.log("VK UNKNOWN ERROR")
            }
        }
    }

    initialPage: Component { Auth { } }
    cover: Qt.resolvedUrl("cover/CoverPage.qml")
}
```

In the component Auth I have that code:

```
Page {
    id: messangesPage

    Button {
        id: mycoolbutton
        text: "button"
        onClicked: {
            vk.getMessanges("lol",0)
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        vk.getMessanges("lol",0)
    }
}
```

So the idea of my code is pretty simple - I have vk object, that must be global. When I call vk.getMessanges, vk send request to the server and after that emit replyReady signal. In onReplyReady I just parse the reply from server and call function in main.js, where I want to execute that function:

```
function processReply(reply) {
    mycoolbutton.text = "mycoolbutton"
}
```

However I got an error:

```
main.js:8: ReferenceError: mycoolbutton is not defined
```

I noticed that if I call processReply() function from component Auth, than everything works fine, but when I call from element applicationWindow than I got that error. I tried to add property alias mycoolbuttonptr : mycoolbutton in the applicationWindow, but I got another error. What I must do in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that main.js is instantiated once for every import you make? If you import main.js from several QML files, you are getting several instances of Main, so if you set a reference to mycoolbutton in one of that instances, that reference is only set on **that** instance.

If you want to have only one `Main` instance, you have to declare it at the begining of the JS file with

```
.pragma library
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access Items by id from JS file. You should pass button as parameter, for example:

```
function processReply(reply, btn) {
    btn.text = "mycoolbutton"
}
```

".pragma library" can be helpful, but doesn't solve problem.

Comment: Having it as a library, you can set a reference to mycoolbutton on the JS library, something like `setCoolButton()`

Comment: Yes, @Smasho, it is also viable way.